# TFS shell integration TortoiseTFS?

Tags: svn, tfs, tortoisesvn

I love TortoiseSVN, as I'm sure many do.

we've fairly recently moved to TFS at work, and I find myself wanting Tortoise for TFS.

I tried the TFS Power Toys ( I'm running under Windows Server 2003) but no icons turned up).

Is it a vista only thing?

Is there a way to get TFS to expose SVN urls like codeplex does? ... i've tried svnbridge but it doesn't seem to always work for me.

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the latest TFS power tools there was shell integration but it requires the following:

- Custom selection during the install (it's not part of the standard install)
- You must be logged into the windows machine using the same accound credentials that you would use to connect to your TFS instance

The folder icons will only look different if you have the workspace mapped appropriately in TFS to your folder

Comment: Hi, i've installed TFS PowerTools but still no icons :(
I didn't see the custom selection part in the install?

Comment: Did you install the October release? During the installer there is a point if you want to do a standard install or a custom install.

Also, you need to be logged into the machine using the windows credentials for the TFS server.

Answer (score 6):

You said that SVNBridge doesn't work for you, but I would recommend giving it a second look and trying to figure out what is not working. I use it here and have no major problems except browsing the repository is slow.

Here are snippets from a doc I wrote for our office on getting it up and running. It might be a bit out of date.

- Run SVNBridge
- Leave the port at 8081
- Hit OK. If a windows firewall dialog comes up, allow it. SVNBridge should appear in your system tray.
- Open Windows Explorer, Right Click in the directory where you want to check out files to, Select TortoiseSVN | Repo-Browser from the context menu.
- Browse to repository http://localhost:8081/yourserver/yourrepository/ from TortoiseSVN (This can be slow)
- Right click on the directory you want to get from the server and check it out.